# Circuit to Disable 24VDC to Load via +24VDC Logic Output

Tags: mosfet, pcb, digital-logic, switches, control

I have a load that is powered by a +24VDC source. The load can draw a max of 400mA. I would like a simple and effective circuit to disable power when a 0-24VDC logic signal is high; in addition, I would like to use as few components as possible to minimize the space taken up on the board (SMT components). I am planning on using MOSFETs since I would like to keep the power quite low. My questions are as follows:

- **Can I use a simple high-side switch with a single P-Channel MOSFET**
  for this application (see image)?

  - What are the limitations of this circuit?

    - I saw similar circuits that used an additional driving MOSFET/transistor, but those circuits were intended to enable--rather than disable--the voltage with the ctrl signal... An additional driving transistor does not seem necessary here since the gate and source voltages are ~the same...
  - Should I be considering a different solution? I looked into relays and other types of switches, but MOSFETs seemed like the most appropriate solution (e.g., take up less space than a relay/don't make clicking sounds, voltage controlled = minimal current draw once gate is charged, etc.)

    - Please provide me with feedback on how I should modify the circuit
      and why (and/or point me to any useful resources)
- **How should I go about spec’ing the various components**?

  - *R_pullup:*

    - To start, I used a 10K value. I read that you should choose a
      resistor with impedance at least 10x smaller than your logic pin. Unfortunately
      I cannot find the impedance for my controller output in its datasheet, but I am assuming it is quite high.
    - Not entirely sure how to calculate the expected current (i.e., for power spec), but I am estimating that it is quite negligible since the MOSFET gate won't draw much--if any--current after initial charge
  - *R_limit:*

    - The controller output is rated for 250mA, 24VDC. I chose ~150R to limit any current spikes due to the MOSFET internal capacitance .
    - Same comment as R_pullup regarding power spec
  - *MOSFET:*

    - What should I look for in the MOSFET specifications?
    - SMT recommendations, if you know any!

Any information you can provide me with would be greatly appreciated! I simulated a version of this circuit on LTspice but am very new to electronics design and would like to gain a more practical understanding.

[image]

Comment: 24V logic sounds like industrial automation. Any reason you can't just hang another relay off the DIN rail?

Comment: Be careful that the gate to source voltage does not exceed it's rated limit when the control signal is brought low. The exact limit will depend upon your choice of MOSFET. However, you may want to tweak the resistor values so that they are not so far apart. By increasing R_limit (or possibly decreasing R_pullup) the voltage on the gate will not be pulled so close to 0V.

Comment: @SolomonSlow It also sounds like any modern truck or heavy machinery. 24V can be found in a lot of diverse applications.